# NextJS - Using Webpack Externals for faster build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a special scenario where i need to build and export my site on runtime. That's mean that i have to provide the site and bundle really quickly.

I have an idea of using Webpack externals by bundling in advance all of my components by that the only thing that Next.JS build will have to do is mostly create the index HTML and with a Webpack plugin i will just inject url of to the externals scripts.

Do you think it is doable ? Do u have maybe a different idea of implementation ?

Comment: Try Custom Webpack nextjs
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Webpack external. All your components could be part of separate library which would be pre-built and you can add as dependency to your project.

Just note that, the faster build using external is debatable. The performance gain would be there but in theory there should be no difference.